# JHipster, Entities Menu Item failed to load for Micro Frontends

Tags: microservices, jhipster, beta

I am using JHipster 8.0.8.beta-1 with Angular, Java, Micro Services, Micro Frontends, no database for my gateway microservice and MSSQL for the database for the microservice server.

I have one gateway microservice and one microservice server.

I have two entities defined in the JDL.

When I create the microservices using the JHipster they are created without any errors.

I create and run the Docker containers for keycloak and consul.

I run the micro service server using the maven command mvnw
I run the micro service gateway using the maven command mvnw

I open up a browser and to go the http://localhost:9092 for the gateway and login
When I click on the Entities menu option I see the two options:

- Failed to load customer entities
- Failed to load licensepool entities

Looking in the console for the browser I see the following:

```
index.ts:7     GET http://localhost:9092/services/licensepool/remoteEntry.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ angular-architects-module-federation-runtime.mjs:44
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:22
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:27
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1344
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:19
loadRemoteModuleEntry @ angular-architects-module-federation-runtime.mjs:40
(anonymous) @ angular-architects-module-federation-runtime.mjs:37
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:22
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:27
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1344
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:19
loadRemoteEntry @ angular-architects-module-federation-runtime.mjs:26
(anonymous) @ angular-architects-module-federation-runtime.mjs:120
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:22
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:27
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1344
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:19
loadRemoteModule @ angular-architects-module-federation-runtime.mjs:68
(anonymous) @ index.ts:7
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:22
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:27
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1344
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:19
loadNavbarItems @ index.ts:6
loadMicrofrontendsEntities @ navbar.component.ts:106
(anonymous) @ navbar.component.ts:61
next @ Subscriber.js:91
_next @ Subscriber.js:60
next @ Subscriber.js:31
(anonymous) @ Subject.js:34
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
next @ Subject.js:27
next @ ReplaySubject.js:22
authenticate @ account.service.ts:28
(anonymous) @ account.service.ts:48
source.subscribe.isUnsub @ tap.js:17
OperatorSubscriber._next @ OperatorSubscriber.js:13
next @ Subscriber.js:31
(anonymous) @ map.js:7
OperatorSubscriber._next @ OperatorSubscriber.js:13
next @ Subscriber.js:31
(anonymous) @ filter.js:6
OperatorSubscriber._next @ OperatorSubscriber.js:13
next @ Subscriber.js:31
subscribe.innerComplete @ mergeInternals.js:25
OperatorSubscriber._next @ OperatorSubscriber.js:13
next @ Subscriber.js:31
source.subscribe.isUnsub @ tap.js:18
OperatorSubscriber._next @ OperatorSubscriber.js:13
next @ Subscriber.js:31
source.subscribe.isUnsub @ tap.js:18
OperatorSubscriber._next @ OperatorSubscriber.js:13
next @ Subscriber.js:31
source.subscribe.isUnsub @ tap.js:18
OperatorSubscriber._next @ OperatorSubscriber.js:13
next @ Subscriber.js:31
subscribe.innerSubscriber @ switchMap.js:14
OperatorSubscriber._next @ OperatorSubscriber.js:13
next @ Subscriber.js:31
onLoad @ http.mjs:1865
_ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:450
(anonymous) @ core.mjs:25881
onInvokeTask @ core.mjs:25881
_ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:449
onInvokeTask @ core.mjs:26182
_ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:449
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:218
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:532
invokeTask @ zone.js:1710
globalCallback @ zone.js:1753
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1777
Zone - XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener:load (async)
onScheduleTask @ core.mjs:25875
_ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:430
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:327
_ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:430
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:261
Zone.scheduleEventTask @ zone.js:287
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2018
(anonymous) @ http.mjs:1951
_trySubscribe @ Observable.js:37
(anonymous) @ Observable.js:31
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
subscribe @ Observable.js:22
source.subscribe.isComplete @ switchMap.js:14
OperatorSubscriber._next @ OperatorSubscriber.js:13
next @ Subscriber.js:31
(anonymous) @ innerFrom.js:51
_trySubscribe @ Observable.js:37
(anonymous) @ Observable.js:31
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
subscribe @ Observable.js:22
(anonymous) @ switchMap.js:10
(anonymous) @ lift.js:10
(anonymous) @ Observable.js:26
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
subscribe @ Observable.js:22
(anonymous) @ tap.js:15
(anonymous) @ lift.js:10
(anonymous) @ Observable.js:26
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
subscribe @ Observable.js:22
(anonymous) @ tap.js:15
(anonymous) @ lift.js:10
(anonymous) @ Observable.js:26
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
subscribe @ Observable.js:22
(anonymous) @ tap.js:15
(anonymous) @ lift.js:10
(anonymous) @ Observable.js:26
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
subscribe @ Observable.js:22
(anonymous) @ finalize.js:5
(anonymous) @ lift.js:10
(anonymous) @ Observable.js:26
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
subscribe @ Observable.js:22
(anonymous) @ finalize.js:5
(anonymous) @ lift.js:10
(anonymous) @ Observable.js:26
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
subscribe @ Observable.js:22
doInnerSub @ mergeInternals.js:19
outerNext @ mergeInternals.js:14
OperatorSubscriber._next @ OperatorSubscriber.js:13
next @ Subscriber.js:31
(anonymous) @ innerFrom.js:51
_trySubscribe @ Observable.js:37
(anonymous) @ Observable.js:31
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
subscribe @ Observable.js:22
mergeInternals @ mergeInternals.js:50
(anonymous) @ mergeMap.js:13
(anonymous) @ lift.js:10
(anonymous) @ Observable.js:26
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
subscribe @ Observable.js:22
(anonymous) @ filter.js:6
(anonymous) @ lift.js:10
(anonymous) @ Observable.js:26
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
subscribe @ Observable.js:22
(anonymous) @ map.js:6
(anonymous) @ lift.js:10
(anonymous) @ Observable.js:26
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
subscribe @ Observable.js:22
(anonymous) @ tap.js:15
(anonymous) @ lift.js:10
(anonymous) @ Observable.js:26
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
subscribe @ Observable.js:22
(anonymous) @ share.js:58
(anonymous) @ lift.js:10
(anonymous) @ Observable.js:26
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
subscribe @ Observable.js:22
(anonymous) @ catchError.js:9
(anonymous) @ lift.js:10
(anonymous) @ Observable.js:26
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
subscribe @ Observable.js:22
ngOnInit @ main.component.ts:29
callHookInternal @ core.mjs:3833
callHook @ core.mjs:3860
callHooks @ core.mjs:3815
executeInitAndCheckHooks @ core.mjs:3765
refreshView @ core.mjs:12458
detectChangesInternal @ core.mjs:12385
detectChanges @ core.mjs:12915
tick @ core.mjs:27330
_loadComponent @ core.mjs:27368
bootstrap @ core.mjs:27305
(anonymous) @ core.mjs:27006
_moduleDoBootstrap @ core.mjs:27006
(anonymous) @ core.mjs:26976
_ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:416
onInvoke @ core.mjs:26195
_ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:415
Zone.run @ zone.js:173
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1319
_ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:450
(anonymous) @ core.mjs:25881
onInvokeTask @ core.mjs:25881
_ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:449
onInvokeTask @ core.mjs:26182
_ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:449
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:218
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:639
Zone - Promise.then (async)
onScheduleTask @ core.mjs:25875
_ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:430
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:327
_ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:430
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:261
Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:281
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:1309
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:1520
(anonymous) @ core.mjs:26972
_callAndReportToErrorHandler @ core.mjs:27083
(anonymous) @ core.mjs:26969
_ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:416
onInvoke @ core.mjs:26195
_ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:415
Zone.run @ zone.js:173
run @ core.mjs:26049
bootstrapModuleFactory @ core.mjs:26948
(anonymous) @ core.mjs:27001
_ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:416
Zone.run @ zone.js:173
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1319
_ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:450
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:218
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:639
Promise.then (async)
nativeScheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:615
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:626
_ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:440
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:261
Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:281
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:1309
resolvePromise @ zone.js:1246
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1162
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1178
webpackJsonpCallback @ main.js:644
(anonymous) @ default-node_modules_ng-bootstrap_ng-bootstrap_fesm2022_ng-bootstrap_mjs.js:1
Show 218 more frames
navbar.component.ts:119 Error loading licensepool entities TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:9092/services/licensepool/remoteEntry.js
```

It appears for some reason the browser could not find the resource at the specified URL. I see no errors displayed for the microservice server and am not able to figure out the issue.

Any advise is appreciated.